# How to fit a String into a rectangle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have an NSString and want to fit it into a rectangle. The rectangle has a specified size, lets say width=150 and height=30. When the String is short and has only one character, it can be as high as the rectangle. More specific: It can have a big font size. But if the string has too much characters and would exceed the bounds of the rectangle, it must become smaller. More specific: It's font size must become smaller, so that it won't exceed the bounds of the rectangle. Is there a way of doing that without messing around in core graphics?

For some reason, UILabel's adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth Property has no effect. The text keeps beeing small even if there is plently of space.

I've set that to

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

but nothing happens. I hope there is another way to do that...

Comment: What do you mean by smaller? Do you mean truncating the string?

Comment: smaller font size / no truncating. updated the question with more detail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several part to `UILabel` that make this possible, but first you have to know if you want to truncate the string or make the font size smaller to fit in the rectangle.

For both cases you'll want to set the `UILabel`'s `numberOfLines` property to `0`, allowing the label to wrap as much as necessary. Then you'll want to set the `frame` of the `UILabel` to match the rectangle you're looking to fit. From there you take one of two paths:

- **Truncation**: Set the `lineBreakMode` property to `UILineBreakModeClip`, `UILineBreakModeHeadTruncation`, `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`, or `UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation` depending on the truncation behavior you're looking for.
- **Resizing**: Set the `lineBreakMode` to either `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` or `UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap' depending on your preference. Then you'll need to enter a loop to figure out the right font size. Start with a reasonable font size (e.g., 12) and:

  - Set the `font` property of the `UILabel` with a `UIFont` that matches that size
  - Call `- (void) sizeToFit` for the `UILabel`.
  - Check the `frame` for the `UILabel`:

    - If the frame will fit within the bounds you need it to, you're done
    - If the frame is still to big, drop the size of the font and repeat the loop

For the latter option you'll want to make sure you're not squeezing the text into oblivion, so you'll want to put a minimum size cap on the font size.

You can get more information from the [UILabel](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) and [UIFont](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.

Answer (score 4):

`adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` adjusts the font size *down*, not up.

Set the font on your UILabel to an appropriately large size, and UILabel will shrink it when necessary to fit in its bounds.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set label font size to desired normal size.
2. Set label minimum font size to
   smallest possible font
   (`minimumFontSize` property)
3. Set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to
   `YES`.

If you need multiple lines, set `lineCount` to 0 as the other poster noted.